# How to implement Login module in Tastypie in Django project

Tags: django, tastypie

I am currently working on a project which requires Api, i choose Tastypie and implemented the following. I want to use tastypie's default features like ApiKeyAuthentication, DjangoAuthorization etc... in my code

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()`enter code here`
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
        resource_name = 'user'

    def override_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/login%s$" %
                (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()),
                self.wrap_view('login'), name="api_login"),
            url(r'^(?P<resource_name>%s)/logout%s$' %
                (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()),
                self.wrap_view('logout'), name='api_logout'),
        ]

    def login(self, request, **kwargs):
        self.method_check(request, allowed=['post'])
        data = self.deserialize(request, request.raw_post_data,format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))

        username = data.get('username', '')
        password = data.get('password', '')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return self.create_response(request, {
                    'success': True
                })
            else:
                return self.create_response(request, {
                    'success': False,
                    'reason': 'disabled',
                    }, HttpForbidden )
        else:
            return self.create_response(request, {
                'success': False,
                'reason': 'incorrect',
                }, HttpUnauthorized )

    def logout(self, request, **kwargs):
        self.method_check(request, allowed=['get'])
        if request.user and request.user.is_authenticated():
            logout(request)
            return self.create_response(request, { 'success': True })
        else:
            return self.create_response(request, { 'success': False }, HttpUnauthorized)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Code Below

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from tastypie.authentication import ApiKeyAuthentication
from tastypie.authorization import DjangoAuthorization
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource


class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'auth/user'
        excludes = ['email', 'password', 'is_superuser']
        # Add it here.
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
```